# CRM 4.0 Custom Activity View

Tags: dynamics-crm-4, dynamic-sql, microsoft-dynamics

**The problem:** We need to display Activities with thier regarding objects fixed set of attributes.

**Example:**
Activity Type; Regarding Object Name; Regarding Object Status; Regarding Object Priority; ...

What is the best way to achieve that?

*I'm thinking to solve this by:*

1. Create a Custom entity and include all 'activitypointer' fields + additional fixed count regarding object fields.
2. Create a Database View that queries all required attributes from tables.
3. Create a RetrieveMultiple Plugin for newly created Custom entity fill it with data directly from Database.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way I would propose is a custom web application that mocks the normal views.  You can use the CRM styles to make it look the same as other views.  On load, have it retrieve all activities you want using SQL if on-premise or RetrieveMultiple if hosted.  This way you would have more flexibility in terms of search and bringing in additional attributes and don't have to mess around with plugins.

Comment: After evaluating various solutions, I believe your solution best fits current business requirements.